# SQL - comparing date to inner select that might return null

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to get all events with start date greater than the start date of a given event id ( e.g. 12345).

I used the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Events 
WHERE StartDate > (SELECT StartDate 
                   FROM Events 
                   WHERE ID = 12345)
```

my questions are:

1. What happens if there is no event with id 12345?
2. What happens if the event 12345 has no startDate i.e. has null value

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: Short answer is, in both the cases you will not get any result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *What happens if there is no event with id 12345?*

Nothing will be returned as the sub-query does not return any rows which in turn will be treated as a `NULL` value in the comparison.

You can however re-write the query to return *something* in that case. But without more information what you are trying to achieve it's hard to tell.

> *What happens if the event 12345 has no startDate i.e. has null value*

Again, nothing will be returned because any comparison of a null value returns "undefined" which - when used as a condition in a where clause - essentially is the same as "false".

If you want, you could treat that null value with some default date though. Which default to choose totally depends on what you want. You could e.g.  use a very early date, or today or a very late date

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE startdate > (SELECT coalesce(startdate, sysdate)
                   FROM events 
                   WHERE id = 12345)
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you'll get no results since nothing is bigger than NULL
(or smaller than or equal to or different from)

```
select  case 
            when (select sysdate from dual where dummy = 'Y') is null 
            then 'Y' 
            else 'N' 
        end           as empty_result_set_is_null

from    dual
;
```

> empty_result_set_is_null
>   Y

```
select  case 
            when sysdate+7 > (select sysdate from dual where dummy = 'Y')
            then 'Y' 
            else 'N' 
        end           as is_bigger 

from    dual
;
```

> is_bigger
>   N

```
select  case 
            when sysdate > (select cast (null as date) from dual)
            then 'Y' 
            else 'N' 
        end           as is_bigger 

from    dual
;
```

> is_bigger
>   N